# a light solution to convert text to pdf in Linux

Tags: linux, pdf

I am looking for a light solution in linux, to *literally* convert a `*.txt` file into `pdf` format. I hope the solution satisfies:

1. lightweight. I know renaming `*.txt` to `*.odt` and then use `libreoffice` is a pathway, but it will load the heavy `libreoffice`.
2. I know `pr|groff -Tpdf` is a solution, yet it does not work literally: it throws away my line-breaks, an may accidentally eat some special marks as escaped labels, making potential bugs. But I still hope to use these old tools as much as possible, because they are stable and fast.

Many thanks!

Comment: Would something like [txt2pdf](http://www.sanface.com/txt2pdf.html) work, or do you need a FOSS solution?

Comment: You can use this single command $ pandoc -o hello.pdf hello.txt

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/27097/how-to-print-a-regular-file-to-pdf-from-command-line

Answer (score 53, accepted):

One way would be to use [**`enscript`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/enscript) followed by [**`ps2pdf`**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps2pdf)

```
enscript -p file.ps file.txt
ps2pdf file.ps file.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution works! Now one may try `enscript file.txt --output=- | ps2pdf - > file.pdf`

Comment: Note that enscript doesn't support UTF-8.

Comment: On OSX, if you only have `pstopdf`, not `ps2pdf`, you can use `enscript file.txt --output=- | pstopdf -o file.pdf`

Comment: If you have `LibreOffice`, you could do the same without installing `enscript`:

`$ soffice --convert-to pdf test.txt --outdir /destination directory/`

Comment: `pandoc input.txt -o output.pdf` gives a better output than `enscript` and `ps2pdf` with the default parameters and it supports UTF-8.