# Batch convert .py (text files) to .pdf on osx

Tags: python, pdf, text, batch-processing

I teach a python course and have a large number of .py files that were submitted for an exam.  I would like to convert all these to pdf so that I can open them in IAnnotate on my ipad, mark them up and return them to students. How can I do a such a conversion in batch mode?

Comment: You can put the following in a Bash loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129029/a-light-solution-to-convert-text-to-pdf-in-linux

Answer (score 6):

Tried on Mavericks:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.py; do
    textutil -convert rtf -font 'Courier New' -fontsize 9 ${file} -output ${file}.rtf
    cupsfilter -D ${file}.rtf > ${file}.pdf
done
```

The resulting files will be named `*.py.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks. Prior to Mavericks, there existed /System/Library/Printers/Libraries/convert which was a wrapper around cupsfilter to convert from rtf to pdf, but using cupsfilter directly as you describe does indeed work under Mavericks.

Comment: Works great, I was expecting to need to install cupsfilter or textutil.