# How does phpmyadmin writes a table in a pdf file?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

There is an export option in phpmyadmin which can be used to write a database table in a pdf file. How does phpmyadmin do that? Basically, what I am asking is if I want to write a table in pdf using command prompt then how can it be done? Is php required somehow to do it or it can be done purely using MySQL command prompt?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no capability within SQL to write to a PDF.  phpMyadmin uses php to do this.  It's open source so you can look at the code if you want

However, rather than copying the method used by phpMyadmin, if you want the capability to do this, I recommend looking into tcpdf or fpdf, which are php libraries designed to handle this.   Take a look here:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/

Comment: gotta love those down votes. Anyway, this should work.  It's relatively easy to install and there are is some good documentation designed to make it relatively easy.  If you then then write a php script to get what you need, format it how you like, and then generate a pdf.    Note, the other answer on this is also fine if you want a raw text version of this converted into a pdf.  In fact there's a ton of software out there that can convert just about any file into this format, including OpenOffice (or *other* Office products)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the results of a query to a text file like this:

```
SELECT * from someTable
INTO OUTFILE 'file.txt'
```

(See: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/)

From there, you can use `enscript` and `ps2pdf` to convert the text to a pdf

```
enscript file.txt --output=- | ps2pdf - > file.pdf
```

(See: [a light solution to convert text to pdf in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129029/a-light-solution-to-convert-text-to-pdf-in-linux))

That's one possible way to do it.